# Блокировка доступа к голосовому каналу определенному пользователю. Discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

Я знаю, что можно заблокировать доступ к голосовому каналу, определенной роли, а как можно ограничить доступ к голосовому каналу определенному пользователю, имея его id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить канал по его id

```
channel = bot.get_channel(Сюда айди канала)
```

И получить юзера по id

```
user = bot.get_user(id юзера)
```

И потом использовать метод [set_permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.set_permissions) для голосового канала, чтобы получилось

```
await channel.set_permissions(user, connect=False)
```

[#как получить канал](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)
[#как получить юзера](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_user)

Comment: Еще хотел подметить, что на случай, если не выданы намерения, лучше использовать `user = await bot.fetch_user(id)` :)